Override dependency in turbo repo
I've got a mono repo setup like this:
apps/
web/
packages/
database/
The web package uses a package that's dependent on a package that is not installed in the web package itself, but in the database package. To be more specific: I'm using the @auth/drizzle-adapter package in the web app which requires drizzle-orm which is only installed in the database package.
My database package exports drizzle-orm - but how to configure my project so that it uses @repo/database for drizzle-orm reports instead of drizzle-orm directly?
Thanks

Solved by switching to pnpm and adding public-hoist-pattern[] = *drizzle* to my .npmrc
